# How to redirect time command output in ksh when invoke shell function with dot command?

Tags: unix, redirect, time, ksh

I need to invoke my shell script with dot command in ksh as
 ". my_function.sh". I also want to use time command and redirect the output to a log file. Without the "." command, everything is fine if I use "(time my_function.sh) 2>&1 | tee -a tmp.log". However, if I use "(time . my_function.sh) 2>&1 | tee -a tmp.log", the time part disappear. Can anyone please let me how to output the time part also? Thx.

Comment: good ques!! , haven't been  able to get the time output redirected to the log too :( !!

Comment: time  output is printed on the standard error .... there have been question like this in server fault -- ` http://serverfault.com/questions/175376/redirect-output-of-time-command-in-unix-into-a-variable-in-bash `

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue and was not able to:

```
% cat my.sh
#!/bin/ksh

echo hi
% (time . my.sh) 2>&1 | tee my.log
hi

real    0m0.00s
user    0m0.00s
sys     0m0.00s
% cat my.log
hi

real    0m0.00s
user    0m0.00s
sys     0m0.00s
```

If you are still having this issue - please share your my_function.sh and full shell output.